# Identify novel from (AI-translated) Bulgarian excerpts: Joris-Karl Huysmans

Tags: identification-request

I encountered a novel that appears to be translated into Bulgarian. The excerpts provided suggest a story involving elements like a mysterious corpse in a garden. The name Joris-Karl Huysmans is mentioned in connection with the work, but I cannot find any corresponding titles in his bibliography. What is this novel? What is its potential original language and author?

Here are some excerpts, translated from Bulgarian via AI:

> The crucifix was upside down, and on it, crucified with his feet upward, hung my accomplice, the muscles of his shoulders had swollen from tension and remained immobilized that way. Every vein in the extremities had tensed inhumanly and protruded relief-like on the flesh. He was naked. His palms and the soles of his feet were nailed with large, silver nails, the tips of which were covered with dried blood. I barely caught my breath as I approached and moved my candle away from the tortured body. The flesh was yellowish, but still not lifeless. As I inspected the body with its feet upward, his head disappeared in the semi-darkness under my knees. I leaned over to illuminate and examine it. The eyes had burst and seemed covered with scales, the forehead was swollen, the lips were open, revealing the tip of the whitened tongue. The throat was cut, a thin stream flowed from it, along the chin, past the ear, through the hair, down to a wide, iron-bound cup. It kept flowing.

> I fell to my knees, my senses blurred, and the nightmarish procession trembled in grotesque, unreal outlines, surrounded by the smoke and the yellow flame of the candles. The man in front of me withdrew his bloody hand from my face and placed it on the embroidered crucifix on his chest. The others approached me, and although I felt strong enough to disperse them and try to escape, my will seemed to be met with a solid wall, against which my desires and strength shattered. The spiritual power of these people surpassed mine, cruelly suppressed it, and I felt, with my eyes blinded, its own pressure, destroying the possibility of resistance, imposing the sinking into the hopelessness of a violent subjection. They stood still. They were silent. Through the gaps in their hoods, their eyes stared at me, but I did not see them; I only saw two dark holes, emitting emptiness, as if the hoods covered skulls.

> The soul is like a lantern. When you don't take care of it, impurities accumulate on it, and the light darkens.

> - But this one - he nudged me in the shoulder - is a corpse and refutes all your words. - This one - the other one jabbed me in the ribs - might be an accidental corpse and doesn't refute anything I've said. - Accidental or not, he's a corpse and lies in your garden. - Could have been thrown there - accidentally, intentionally... - Quite a throw - there's at least a hundred meters to the fence.

- link to the book cover https://i970.photobucket.com/albums/ae188/deadface79/darkside/pepel.jpg
- The year of publishing in Bulgaria is 1992
- There is no copyright nor the original title of the novel
- The publisher name is AL and there is no actual information about them
- I've found the translator's name and will try to find more about them
- The Bulgarian title is "Пепелявият" and according to ChatGPT it can be translated as "The Ashen One".

Comment: Hi ,You have provided quite detailed excerpts which is great . Even so as much additional  information as possible not simply the content but also the book itself ,cover art , illustration ,  publsiher , dates if known  ( when published , when read  ) . As Sherlock Holmes was wont to say at the start when interviewing clients " Omit no detail however slight". This wiki is helpful :  https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info

Comment: Thank you, I've provided some aditional information.

Comment: Just to be clear, was the "translated text" provided by the AI in response to a prompt, or did you provide the text, and then asked the AI to translate it? Some bits of that description sound like an excerpt from *LÀ-BAS*, where he is describing a German piece of art depicting the crucifixion of Jesus, and Chat-GPT is fond of making up stories based on snippets of someone else's work.

Comment: "... the suffering flesh held to earth by the enormous spike piercing the feet. Dislocated, almost ripped out of their sockets, the arms of the Christ seemed trammelled by the knotty cords of the straining muscles. The laboured tendons of the armpits seemed ready to snap. The fingers, wide apart, were contorted in an arrested gesture in which were supplication and reproach but also benediction. The trembling thighs were greasy with sweat...."

Comment: Of course, it could also be that the reference to Joris-Karl Huysmans might have been that he also had an incredibly violent crucifixion described in his book.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. When and where did you encounter this novel? If it's online, please provide a link. Thanks!

Comment: @SeanDuggan I've found some excerpts online and asked ChatGPT to translate it. I've read this novel more than 25 years ago and if I recall correctly the quoted text is describing the murdering scene of the protagonists partner. Despite not being a masterpiece the novel is very intriguing and is mixing very well a different kind of genres as mystery, suspense a lili bit of noir, fantasy and it works very well. I was fascinated and kind of skeptical to read the author is Joris-Karl Huysmans and it seemed to me unbelievable to fiind someone using this style in 19th century.

Comment: @verbose Hi! Nope I didn't find it online, it's a book (supposedly) translated into Bulgarian.

Comment: @i6x86: Is there any chance that you could point out where you found the excerpts? It is good to know that this is something that you read before.

Comment: @SeanDuggan sure, I've found them here https://www.forum.king-bg.info/viewtopic.php?t=1032 it's a kind of forum and the op is also skeptical about the author being Huysmans.

Comment: Part of me wants to say *Foucault's Pendulum* by Umberto Eco, but Belbo does hanging on the pendulum, not on a cross.

Comment: This book is available in several Bulgarian libraries. All of them list it this way: _Прев. от англ. изд. - Ориг. загл. на фр. ез. - На загл. с. ав. погрешно означен Жорис-Карл Юсманс_ which means "translation from English, original title in French, Joris-Karl Huysmans erroneously denoted as author on the front page" http://ilib.libpanagyurishte.com/bg/bool-simp.php?db=ekk&outType=0&bool=%28%C0%C2%3D%DE%E8%F1%EC%E0%ED%F1%2C+%C6%EE%F0%E8%F1-%CA%E0%F0%EB%29&recordsPerPage=12&page=1&filterLanguage=

Comment: @Quassnoi I've been looking at those trying to find answer (unsuccessfully) and I think 'erroneously denoted' refers to the spelling of author's name: 'Юсманс' instead of 'Юисманс'. I agree it's likely that the original author is not the listed one.